# Get resources list in angular formio

Tags: angular, formio

While using this [starter kit](https://github.com/formio/angular-app-starterkit), Im only able to get a list of forms.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormioGrid } from 'angular-formio/grid';
import { FormManagerModule, FormManagerRoutes, FormManagerService, FormManagerConfig } from 'angular-formio/manager';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormioGrid,
    FormManagerModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(FormManagerRoutes())
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
    FormManagerService,
    {provide: FormManagerConfig, useValue: {
        tag: 'common'
      }}
  ]
})
export class FormModule { }
```

Which points to:

```
{api_url}/form?tags=common&type=form&limit=10&skip=0
```

I need a way to get resources, something like this:

```
{api_url}/form?tags=common&type=resource&limit=10&skip=0
```

Tried passing a parameter to provider with no luck.

```
providers: [
    FormManagerService,
    {provide: FormManagerConfig, useValue: {
        tag: 'common',
        type: 'resource'
      }}
  ]
```

What I'm missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `type` & `tags` value from `query` property binding of `formio-grid` component

```
<formio-grid
    ...
    [query]="{tags: 'common', type: 'resource'}"
    ...
>
</formio-grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, but sorry, I don't get it. In which file is this?

Comment: Use it on formio component, can you add html code where you used formio?

Comment: Im not sure. I don't have any view here. Everything is inside node_modules. My (almost) only files are src/app/form/form.module.ts and form.module.spec.ts (with the code I posted above).

Comment: @PankajParkar is correct. Here is the code that does it for forms. You just need to do the same thing but use resource for the type. https://github.com/formio/angular-formio/blob/master/src/manager/index/index.component.html

Comment: Thank you Pankaj, now I understand. Marked as answered. And thank YOU Travis for this awesome platform.